# about Struct Memory Managemet in C

Tags: c, memory

```
typedef struct{
 int a:1, b:1;
}test;
```

`a` and `b` are capable to store a number up to 255. If somehow variable `a` stores a bigger value than that, this will affect the value of `b`,right? I am terrible at memory management. Also, is it recommended to alter the size of a field in a struct this way?

Comment: *`a` and `b` are capable to store a number up to `255`* -- No! a and b are only supposed to store values `0` or `-1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most variables in C have a size that is an integral number of bytes. Bit-fields are a part of a structure that *don't
necessarily* occupy a integral number of bytes; *they can any number of bits*. Multiple bit-fields can be packed into a
single storage unit. Here these are 1 bit bitfiels capable of holding `0` and `-1`.

And in case there is a larger number being stored in a 1 bit bitfield then this would be *undefined behavior* (signed overflow).

More prominently use `unsigned` type in bit field in this case

```
typedef struct{
 unsigned int a:1, b:1;
}test;
```

Comment: Just a side question. Does assignment count as overflow?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya.: I would say so.

Comment: @coderredoc (I missread 'byte' with 'bit' on a source, and this led to confusion) Thank you for clarification!